# Why is the asc file associated with Fusion CanopyModel different from the GeoTiff I create?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, lidar, fusion

I'm working in Python (using PyQGIS) to create a digital surface model from .las data. When I use fusion:canopymodel it creates a .dtm file, and a .asc file. I then convert the .dtm file to .tiff using fusion:dtmtotif.

```
alg_params_dsm = {
    'ADVANCED_MODIFIERS': '',
    'ASCII': True,
    'CELLSIZE': 1,
    'CLASS': '',
    'GROUND': '',#run_folder+'DEM.dtm', don't use ground.dtm according to FL
    'INPUT': run_folder+'ground_outside_b.las'+';'+run_folder+'buildings_inside_b.las',
    'MEDIAN': '',
    'SLOPE': False,
    'SMOOTH': '',
    'VERSION64': True,
    'XYUNITS': 0,
    'ZUNITS': 0,
    'OUTPUT': run_folder+'DSM.dtm'
    }
DSM = processing.run('fusion:canopymodel', alg_params_dsm)

# converts the .dtm to .tif using fusion:dtm2tif
processing.run("fusion:dtm2tif",{'INPUT':run_folder+'DSM.dtm','MASK':False,'OUTPUT':run_folder+'DSM.tif'})
```

If I view both the asc and tif files in QGIS, the value ranges are significantly different. Should I be ignoring the asc file as it's just an artifact of the dtm production, or is something going wrong here?

ASC

```
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/weedingb/Desktop/utas_solweig_run/SOLWEIG_run_09-04-2021_1023/DSMasc.asc', 'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE' : 'C:/Users/weedingb/Desktop/utas_solweig_run/asc_stats.html' }

Execution completed in 0.25 seconds
Results:
{'MAX': 217.020004,
'MEAN': 87.76850797590447,
'MIN': 1.335127,
'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE': 'C:/Users/weedingb/Desktop/utas_solweig_run/asc_stats.html',
'RANGE': 215.684877,
'STD_DEV': 49.898164110912916,
'SUM': 87853380.12311716,
'SUM_OF_SQUARES': 2492231954.310662}
```

TIF

```
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/weedingb/Desktop/utas_solweig_run/SOLWEIG_run_09-04-2021_1023/DSMtif.tif', 'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE' : 'C:/Users/weedingb/Desktop/utas_solweig_run/dsm_stats.html' }

Execution completed in 0.03 seconds
Results:
{'MAX': 255.0,
'MEAN': 101.98007774877166,
'MIN': 0.0,
'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE': 'C:/Users/weedingb/Desktop/utas_solweig_run/dsm_stats.html',
'RANGE': 255.0,
'STD_DEV': 58.94115770080025,
'SUM': 102388304.0,
'SUM_OF_SQUARES': 3487963259.515189}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the cell values are different and not just the statistics? You can't take the values in the table of contents as being exact.

Comment: Have checked using stats in QGIS and they are definitely different:

Answer (score 2):

Have potentially found the reason. Looking to the Fusion manual, it states that for dtm2tiff:
[image]

This suggests that the dtm values are scaled to between 1 and 255. However, I don't understand how height information is preserved under scaling like that? Are min and max values stored somewhere in the tif file to indicate the 'real' values of the 1-255?

Comment: That would do it, a rendered value and not a data value - even if your range was sea level to Mount Everest the range would still be 1-255, assuming 0 is reserved for NoData.

Comment: I would find some other way of converting your dtm to geotiff that output in an appropriate data type rather than byte 0-255 values.