# How does GeoTIFF file store elevation data?

Tags: python, pyqgis, geotiff-tiff, dem, fusion

I'm trying to understand how elevation data is stored in GeoTIFF files, when used for Digital Elevation/Surface Models. My very basic understanding is that in a GeoTIFF file (or at least those produced by Fusion's `dtm2tif` function), each pixel has a value associated with it for each band, and that these values are 0 if no data is present, and between 1 and 255 for data.

Is there a piece of metadata in the GeoTIFF that indicates how to scale between 1-255 to the elevation data in the elevation model?

Is there an easy way of accessing this scaling in python?

Comment: GeoTIFFs can store more than just 8bit (byte) 0-255 values. You can have 16, 32, 64 or more bit signed or unsigned integers, floating point so there's no need for any scaling.

Comment: https://gwlucastrig.github.io/gridfour/notes/ElevationGeoTiff1.html

Comment: @Aaron From the previous question today by the same user https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393381/why-is-the-asc-file-associated-with-fusion-canopymodel-different-from-the-geotif#comment643763_393381 centres around the fusion rendering of DTM2TIF, the ASC file should contain floating point data which can be converted to GeoTIFF single precision floating point, I'm not sure how to do that in python but a utility like gdal_translate should do that no problem.

Comment: If Fusion converts the original DEM into integer range 1-255 only Fusion knows the relation. If Fusion needs to know the scale factor afterwards then I guess that it saves some metadata either into the TIFF tags or into some additional files. If it is using TIFF only for visualizing the data then maybe it does not care about the metadata.